# Regex matching characters after pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract strings after a pattern in a long string, which is basically HTML output of a page.

For example; I need to extract target of href tag from this string

```
<h2 class=\ "product-name\"><a href=\"/erkek-ayakkabi-spor-gri-17sfd3007141340-p\" title=\"...">...</a></h2>\r\n
```

What I need from this: erkek-ayakkabi-spor-gri-17sfd3007141340-p

But also I need to find strings alike to the one above. SO I need to search for `href` tags after `class=\ "product-name\"` in the HTML string.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107).

Comment: I'm working on an already writen code, I just need to do a minimal change. I don't have time to fundamentally change the way we parse html now. Maybe later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this.

Regex:

```
class=\"product-name\"(.*)<a\shref=\"(.*?)\"
```

Updated Regex:

```
class=\"product-name\".*<a\shref=\"(.*?)\"
```

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/8HOSpz/3/).

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string data = "<h2 class=\"product-name\"><a href=\"erkek-ayakkabi-spor-gri-17sfd3007141340-p\" title=\"...\">...</a></h2>\r\n<h2 class=\"test-name\"><a href=\"erkek-ayakkabi-spor-gri-17sfd3007141340-p\" title=\"...\">...</a></h2>\r\n<h2 class=\"product-name\"><a href=\"erkek-ayakkabi-spor-gri-17sfd3007141340-p\" title=\"...\">...</a></h2>\r\n";
        //string regex = "class=\"product-name\"(.*)<a\\shref=\"(.*?)\"";
        string regex = "class=\"product-name\".*<a\\shref=\"(.*?)\"";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(data, regex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
        foreach(Match item in matches)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Value: " + item.Groups[2]);
            Console.WriteLine("Value: " + item.Groups[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SrNkbz).

Comment: Damn, I literally just wrote the exact same code... :)

Comment: why do you need the first group?

Comment: If there is others `tag` before `a` after `class="product-name"`.

Comment: i still don't understand. `.*` will be enough, why`(.*)`